# C# Async-Await throwing AggregateException on Task.WaitAll

Tags: c#, async-await, quartz.net

I have a Quartz.NET recurring job based on cron expression in a .NET 8 Worker Service. The job is supposed to invoke 2 external APIs and then perform some processing on the API responses downstream.

To increase throughput, I have invoked the APIs using `Task Parallel Library`. So, I have to wait for both the tasks to finish before I can start processing. The implementation looks somewhat like this:

```
private void GetCarStatusAndPositionalInformation(
    IJobExecutionContext context, 
    string terminalNumber)
{
    CarInfo? carInfo = null; CarStatusInfo? carStatusInfo = null; 
    try
    {
        var getCarInformation = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var carInfoResponse = await _apiClient.QueryCarInformation(
                terminalNumber, context.CancellationToken);

            if (carInfoResponse?.CarInfo != null)
            {
                carInfo = carInfoResponse.CarInfo;
            }
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        context.CancellationToken)
        .ContinueWith(
            continuationAction =>
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("Failed to get car info for terminal number: {terminalNumber}", terminalNumber);
            },
            context.CancellationToken,
            TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted,
            TaskScheduler.Current);

        var getCarStatusInformation = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var carStatusInfoResponse = await _apiClient.GetCarStatusInfoAsync(
                terminalNumber, context.CancellationToken);

            if (carStatusInfoResponse?.CarStatusInfo != null)
            {
                carStatusInfo = carStatusInfoResponse.CarStatusInfo;
            }
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        context.CancellationToken)
        .ContinueWith(
            continuationAction =>
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("Failed to get car info for terminal number: {terminalNumber}", terminalNumber);
            },
            context.CancellationToken,
            TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted,
            TaskScheduler.Current);

        

        Task.WaitAll(
            [getCarInformation, getCarStatusInformation], timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

        if (carInfo != null) && carStatusInfo != null) 
        { 
            // Do some processing
        }
    }
    catch (AggregateException aex)
    {

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, "Failed to obtain car status & positional information for: {terminalNumber}", terminalNumber);
    }
}
```

Why am I always getting `AggregateException` with InnerException saying the tasks have been canceled?

Comment: Are the tasks actually completing before the timeout? How do you know?

Comment: First, I'd clean up a little: Don't use `ContinueWith`, await. And put Logging on Failure _into_ the method. Don't `await Task.CompletedTask;` - that doesn't make any sense. Then, extend the timeout / lift it temporarily to take measurements on how long the api calls take on average, min and max ... unfortunately, all this doesn't give you a difinitive answer, so it'll have to remain a comment. But I am confident, these measures will take you one step towards a solution.

Comment: Ah, I think I've got it: The problem _is_ using .ContinueWith. The Task you reference in `getCarInfo` is the _continuation_, **not the one you create** with `Task.Run`. So in `Task.WaitAll` you are waiting for **both to _fail_**. Which will time out if they don't.

Comment: ^^ https://dotnetfiddle.net/MP1P4X

Comment: You also should `await Task.WhenAll` instead of `Task.WaitAll`

Comment: _"Which will time out if they don't."_ - correction: my little experiment on dotnetfiddle threw a TaskCancelledException.

Comment: Thanks @Fildor, your sample code helps.

Comment: The line `if (carInfo != null) && carStatusInfo != null)` is not real code. Can you post real code?

Comment: I'd wrap your `_apiClient` calls and put your error logging in there. Your code is attempting to do two purposes. You really could get it all down to a couple of lines of code. Had you provided a [mcve] I would attempt to show you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies within the way you constructed the Tasks.

`getCarInformation` and `getCarStatusInformation` actually reference the *continuations*, not the Tasks you were expecting.

Now, the "fast and dirty" solution would be to take two steps:

```
var getCarInformation = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var carInfoResponse = await _apiClient.QueryCarInformation(
                terminalNumber, context.CancellationToken);

            if (carInfoResponse?.CarInfo != null)
            {
                carInfo = carInfoResponse.CarInfo;
            }
            await Task.CompletedTask; // <- this makes no sense, btw
        },
        context.CancellationToken);
// ^^ Now you are referencing the Task you expected to reference
getCarInformation 
        .ContinueWith(
            continuationAction =>
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("Failed to get car info for terminal number: {terminalNumber}", terminalNumber);
            },
            context.CancellationToken,
            TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted,
            TaskScheduler.Current);
```

**But cleaner** would be to *not use* `ContinueWith` at all. Just move the failure-logging into the Task itself.

```
var getCarInformation = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    try
    {
            var carInfoResponse = await _apiClient.QueryCarInformation(
                terminalNumber, context.CancellationToken);

            if (carInfoResponse?.CarInfo != null)
            {
                carInfo = carInfoResponse.CarInfo;
            }
    } 
    catch (Exception)
    {
        _logger.LogWarning("Failed to get car info for terminal number: {terminalNumber}", terminalNumber);
        throw; // Or better not throw? Depends on what you need to do.
    }
}, context.CancellationToken);
```

Or just let the Exceptions bubble up. But be aware that this has some caveats. Especially if you need to handle *both* (if both fail). In that `WhenAll` (and I am not sure about `WaitAll`) would then swallow exceptions.

See: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/7011#issuecomment-988018459

Answer (score 1):

Write two ordinary async methods with exception handlers. Example:

```
private async Task GetCarInformation() 
{
    try
    {
        var carInfoResponse = await _apiClient.QueryCarInformation(
            terminalNumber, context.CancellationToken);

        if (carInfoResponse?.CarInfo != null)
        {
            carInfo = carInfoResponse.CarInfo;
        }
    }
    catch(HttpRequestException exception)
    {
        _logger.LogWarning("...");
    }
}
```

Now call them and wait for them.

```
Task.WaitAll( new[] {
    Task.Run(GetCarInformation),
    Task.Run(GetCarStatusInformation)
    },
    timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
);
```

Or if you want to be stingy with threads:

```
Task.Run( async () =>
    {
        await Task.WhenAll( new [] {
            GetCarInformation(),
            GetCarStatusInformation()
            });
    },
    timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
).Wait();
```